Pauli exclusion principle for arbitrarily spacelike separated electrons
Consider two electrons both in spin up states that are spacelike separated. But because all quantum fluctuations travel at or below the speed of light the two electrons are not going to interact at all and will not feel each others presence. So, technically, it is possible to prepare two spacelike separated electrons that are arbitrarily close to each other (in spacelike sense) both in the spin up state. Isn't that a violation of the Pauli exclusion principle? Or is there something I am overlooking in my thinking?

What do you mean by quantum fluctuations in this context? After all, quantum mechanics is nonlocal, so the electrons can fell each others' presence if they are entangled.

@LukasNullmeier I meant the virtual photons or any other force carriers.

@LukasNullmeier Do you have any reference for that assertion of yours?

Concerning nonlocality you can read http://cds.cern.ch/record/142461/files/198009299.pdf?version=1

What do you mean by "spacelike separated electrons"? Events can be space-like separated...

Possibly related: Struggling to understand Identical particles.

@TobiasFünke No it is fine. I just overthought about it.

Pauli's exclusion principle is not a force. It's a principle, which we impose onto the state of nature in order to obtain the correct answer. Thus, there is no way around it. However, if you find out why this is the case or how this can be violated, please let me know. We are going to publish together and share a Nobel price. ;)
You have probably heard this statement before: "[...] the only thing that quantum theory has going for it is that it is unquestionably correct." Unfortunately, this is true. My professor once told me: "Don't ask me this question. I am not here to answer these kind of questions, but to make you study the math until you forget all your questions."

Rather sad attitude of the professor

@LukasNullmeier indeed, but ultimately physics does in fact not answer questions about why nature's fundamental aspects "are the way they are". It can make connections and establish causal relationships, that's about it.

This attitude is akin to “shut up and calculate.” It’s sad because it avoids interesting questions, but it is wise in that physics is ill-equipped to deal with philosophical questions.

I admired him. He was a great teacher and he knew that speculating about a subject for which no answer exists, is not the way to go forward. Basically he expressed "if you are not getting an answer, you are probably asking the wrong question". I also agree with him in the point that if you studied a subject hard enough, most initial questions become irrelevant. Finally, a why questions usually can only be answered "outside the system".
